# codeigniter 4 enable users to define their own routes

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I've started with Codeigniter 4 today. I have an app that I've built with Codeigniter 3 and now I want to upgrade it to CI4. The first thing is to upgrade routes. I have a simple but GREAT solution by enabling users to define their own routes with a simple page, like this:

[image]

And it was super easy, just needed to load and update Routes.php file - arrays of routes.

Now, as I am looking at app/config/Routes.php in CI4 I see it is not a simple array but there is much more to it. So, my question is what would be the simplest way to enable users to define their own routes with a webpage?

Comment: Is there a base url that is same for all these routes?

Comment: @DhavalChheda well I don't understand your point. The problem that I see with CI4 is that things are quite different from CI3 style, So I can't just simple load Routes.php on a page that the user can edit as I did with CI3 (image above). I will have to load and remap the CI3 routes.php file to a CI4 as I can see. That way I will have to do the least amount of changes to the existing system.

Comment: Dhaval Chheda asked a legitimate question as the answer depends on how your app works e.g. if there's a default base url or controller for all these routes. Could you maybe give us some relevant code of how you did it before?